# Noindex no seo value URLs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have no-indexed URLs matching below pattern. Is there any other pattern that could be added?

[image]

Comment: Did you check link that I attached to my answer? This can be also adapted to backend solution.

Comment: I don't think it covers all the patterns. For example ?product_list_dir=asc

Comment: product_list_dir is starting with catalogsearch or in another case with question mark so it covered with what is written on that link

Answer (score 1):

You can add this:

```
Disallow: /*?dir*
Disallow: /*?dir=desc
Disallow: /*?dir=asc
Disallow: /*?limit=all
Disallow: /*?mode*
```

More here

https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-robots/